# Indy10 - Reverse Proxy

Tags: delphi, proxy, indy

Интересует способ реализации reverse-proxy server.
Под рукой имеется Indy 10, и сам вопрос стоит в интересе, возможно ли реализовать данное чудо на инди? Или всё же, придется искать другие варианты?

У меня есть небольшой план, карта, скажем вот она:
Отправка даннных от клиента на бексервер и далее на обработку Windows Сервером.

```
  [Client] => [BackServer] => [Windows Server]
```

Отправка данных от Windows Server на бексервер и дальше к клиенту.

```
  [Windows Server] => [BackServer] => [Client]
```

Пытался сделать костыль на WinSocket'ах, но ничего не вышло, т.к. здесь нужно построить правильную цепочку ожиданий для Windows Server'а.

Писал всё на Delphi. Хочу и закончить всё на нём, но соответствующей документации по компоненту IdSocksServer из Indy10  мне найти не удалось.

Буду рад любому совету, возможно по реализации на чем-то другом или с другими компонентами. Спасибо!

Comment: у меня аналогичная проблема: в сети нашел примере решение на TServerSocket и TClientSocket (из ScktComp). В роде получилось, и передается но без исключений на все запросы сервер отвечает... поэтому страница не всегда грузиться. тоже предполагаю что то связано со временем [Client - браузер] => [backServer (TServerSocket -> TClientSoket)] => [web server] [Client - браузер] <= [backServer (TServerSocket <- TClientSoket)] {не всегда приходит ответ} [web server]

Answer (score 0):

А что не получилось с сокетами? Все же предельно просто

1. На `BackServer` создается слушающий сокет
2. При accept'е на `BackServer` создается клиентский сокет на `Windows Server` и связывается с accept-сокетом
3. Все пакеты из внешней сети, пришедшие на accept-сокет пересылаются на соответствующий ему клиентский сокет
4. Все пакеты пришедшие на клиентский сокет пересылаются на соответствующий ему accept-сокет
5. При закрытии accept-сокета закрывать соответствующий ему клиентский сокет

Comment: Безусловно вы правы. Но проблема имеется всё же...

Comment: Может стоит ее озвучить?

Comment: У меня не получается лишь одно. Реализовать правильную цепочку ожиданий. 

Например: я шлю бексерверу 10 соединений, и все 10 пакетов передаются на Windows через BackServer.

По идее: `Windows` слушает `BackServer` с помощью TCP соединения, при получении данных, я создаю поток для обработки данных, и после возвращаю их на `BackServer`.

Всё ли правильно? Если да, то следующая возникшая проблема в том, что если на другой стороне не будет Клиента, то при подключении этого клиента, ему сразу же будет возвращено 10 пакетов (на первое рукопожатие с BackServer'ом)

Comment: Нет, конечно. BackServer шлет пакеты не Клиенту, а в Сокет. Если Клиент отвалился, то по 5 пункту закрываются оба сокета и все неотосланные пакеты пропадают либо на BackServer, либо на ВинСервер

Comment: И никто никого не ждет. Все должно работать на асинхронных сокетах

Comment: Я делал Relay между сокетами, как ты и говоришь. 

Windows у меня держал постоянное соединение c BackServer'ом (не разрывая сокет), я уже и пытался ReuseSocket делать, но всё без результатно... Клиент как подключился, и не может повторно связаться с сокетом (от Windows), первый раз данные проходят - нормально, но второй раз не хотят идти...

Скоро приеду домой приложу код.